# nested dictionaries in bash

Tags: bash, dictionary

I saw it is possible to generate a dict using bash 4 :

```
declare -A dict=( ["John"]="23" ["Jackie"]="21" )
```

My question is can we assign another dictionary as value ?

For example having a structure like :

```
declare -A dict=( ["John"]=["age"="23" "weight"="150"] ["Jackie"]=["age"="21" "weight"="140"] )
```

Which would represents a structure like:

```
John:
    age: 23
    weight: 150


Jackie:
    age: 21
    weight: 140
```

I thought to use 2 dictionaries however I don't know if this is the best way to achieve nested dict in bash :

```
declare -A John=( ["age"]="23" ["weight"]="150" )
declare -A dict=( ["John"]=${John} )
```

In this case, I could not access `age` or `weight` variables.

Thanks

Comment: `bash` does not support nested arrays. Use a different language if you need more complex data structures.

Comment: Using something like Python would be easier here.

Comment: You *could* make parallel arrays. `declare -A age=( "John"]="23" ["Jackie"]="21" ); declare -A weight=( ["John"]="150" ["Jackie"]="140" );` It isn't perfect, but it does work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Althought bash does not support nested arrays as others comment,
if your `bash` version is 4.3 or newer, `declare` has an `-n` option
to define a refence to the variable name which works as something like
a `C` pointer.
Then you can say:

```
declare -A John=( ["age"]="23" ["weight"]="150" )
declare -A Jackie=( ["age"]="21" ["weight"]="140" )
declare -a dict=("John" "Jackie")

for member in "${dict[@]}"; do
    echo "$member :"
    declare -n p="$member"  # now p is a reference to a variable "$member"
    for attr in "${!p[@]}"; do
        echo "    $attr : ${p[$attr]}"
    done
done
```

The output:

```
John :
    weight : 150
    age : 23
Jackie :
    weight : 140
    age : 21
```

Note that the `-n` option is not a well-used function and has some limitations.

Comment: thank you for the `declare -n` feature ! very useful.

Comment: This method does not allow key name with dash in it.

Comment: @intijk thank you for the comment. Absolutely right. The key name should be a valid bash variable name. I should have clealy mentioned about it. Cheers.